# C++ How to multiply values of vector using pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I keep getting stuck trying to multiply every value in my generated vector using the function triple3 shown in the code below. What I'm trying to do is use my vector which I named array3 and multiply it by three using the function triple3(array3); but I can't figure out what this error message means:

```
  indirection
  requires
  pointer
  operand
  ('vector<int>'
  invalid)
*v[i]...
^~~~~
1 warning and 1 error generated.
```

The code that is use is displayed below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void double3(int *v);
void triple3(vector<int> *v);
void displayVector3(vector<int> v);


int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int size = 10;
    vector<int> array3;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        array3.push_back(rand() % 51 + 50);
    }
//The following code is used to display the first three arrays
    cout << "Arrays after loading them with random numbers in the range [50,100]:"; 

    cout << "\nArray3:\t";
    for(int i = 0; i < array3.size(); i++){
        cout << setw(4) << left << array3[i] << "  ";
    }

//The following code displays the arrays after they have been doubled
    cout << "\n\nArrays after calling a function element by"
         << " element to double each element in the arrays:";

    cout << "\nArray3:\t";
    for(int v : array3){
        double3(&v);
        cout << setw(4) << left << v << "  ";
    }

//The following code displays the arrays after they have been tripled
    cout << "\n\nArrays after passing them to a function"
         << " to triple each element in the arrays:";

    cout << "\nArray3:\t";
        triple3(&array3);
        displayVector3(array3);

    cout << "\n\n";

    cout << "Press enter to continue...\n\n";
    cin.get();
}

void double3(int *v){
    *v *= 2;
}
void triple3(vector<int> *v){
    const int value = 3;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
    *v[i] *= value;}
}

void displayVector3(vector<int> vect){
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    cout << setw(4) << left << vect[i] << "  ";
}
```

Comment: The `[]` operator precedes the `*` operator. Change `*v[i]` to `(*v)[i]`.

Comment: BTW, the best would be to pass `vector<int>&` instead of `vector<int>*`. Then you won't even need to use the `*`.

Comment: BTW, change `displayVector3(vector<int> vect)` to `displayVector3(const vector<int>& vect)`.

Comment: I understand that calling the vector by reference using a reference is easier that calling the vector by reference using a pointer. For our class assignment we were directed to pass it using a pointer. Thank you for your help. I will work off of your advice.

Comment: I'm just one guy in this comment-thread :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to make `v` a *reference* to an `int` in

```
for(int& v : array3){
    double3(&v);
    cout << setw(4) << left << v << "  ";
}
```

BTW, your `double3` should preferably take a reference too, so declare it as

```
void double3(int&);
```

and define (i.e. implement) it as

```
void double3(int& i) { i *= 2; }
```

then just call `double3(v)` in your `for` loop

and likewise for several other functions, e.g. `triple3` (then you'll code `v[i] *= value;` in it and your problem would be solved)

Comment: You got a good point of saying v should be passed in as a ref, although it doesn't solve the error. Voted.

Answer (score 2):

[Subscript operators are evaluated before indirection (*)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

So that line evaluates the same as `*(v[i]) *= value;` - `v[i]` would be a reference to a `vector<int>` somewhere in stack memory that you don't want to access, and the indirection operator `*` is meaningless when applied to a `vector<int>` reference.

To fix the compile error, be explicit with your operation ordering:

```
(*v)[i] *= value;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `std::transform` to transform the elements in a STL container.

```
std::transform(source.begin(), source.end(), destination.begin(), [](const int& param) { return param * 3; });
```

For more on std::transform refer to [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that *v[i] is not right. You should try changing it to (*v)[i].